# Why Curl Request in PHP sometimes work and others do not?

Tags: php, curl

On a ubuntu server I'm running the following PHP code and sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. The parts of the code that are commented on have already tested all possible variations and were not successful.

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.americanas.com.br/');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w'));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r(curl_error($ch));
```

Below is a snapshot of it that I was able to do with the return of two requests, one that worked and one that did not. I noticed that each request is directed to a different IP, and the server's certificate also changes.

[image: a busy cat]

On the same server, executing a corresponding request via the command line always works:

```
curl --verbose https://www.americanas.com.br
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 4):

After many tests I come to some conclusions.

Every structure of the site, it seems, is behind a cluster of servers, which explains the large amount of IPs when resolving his DNS in various DNS services.

This my particular problem was caused by the DNS server used by my hosting. It was returning an IP to the site that was not working with my cURL requests via PHP.

I was able to work around this problem by changing the DNS server of the requests:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS, '1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8');
```

Manually selecting an IP also worked.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, ['www.americanas.com.br:443:23.36.73.68']);
```

I learned many new things with this problem, I hope it can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to the server that executes curls requests as much it's related to the domain itself and dns of the domain like cloudflare also if website have check on http and https requests so it may block requests partially so you make request and it gives response while other one blocked

Answer (score 1):

`On the same server, executing a corresponding request via the command line always works`

the only difference should be the user-agent..

curl the cli program always adds a user-agent, libcurl does not, and many websites blocks requests with no user-agent header. GoogleDNS knows of 3 different servers for www.americanas.com.br, and i guess *SOME* of their servers allow requests with no user-agent header, and some of their servers does not.

```
$ nslookup www.americanas.com.br
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.americanas.com.br   canonical name = wildsan.b2wdigital.com.edgekey.net.
wildsan.b2wdigital.com.edgekey.net      canonical name = e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net.
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 23.52.34.144
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 2a02:26f0:e2:48c::19fe
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 2a02:26f0:e2:4a1::19fe
```

if i'm correct, then the solution is to add a User-Agent header, if you want to be generic then something like

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'libcurl/' . (curl_version()['version']) . ' php/' . PHP_VERSION);
```

- edit: originally i ran out of time in the middle of writing this post, and the original version didn't make much sense, it should make sense now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I did not put it in the example code above, I had tested the code by putting the full http header, simulating browser access, also unsuccessfully. `Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control 
no-cache
Connection 
keep-alive
Host 
www.americanas.com.br
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0`

Answer (score 1):

Now things are getting clearer. The site uses Akamai's services, similar to cloudflare.

Some of the various servers are blocking requests according to the User-Agent, those used by standard browsers, for example.

The solution indicated by the above friend would work as well as running via terminal worked, because User-Agent: curl / 7.50.3 is not locked.

I just sent a request with a random User-Agent and .... bingo. Worked perfectly.